# Iterating over rows in NumPy array, how do I properly take care of this 1D vs 2D case, where I want the 1D treated as an entire row for indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I have a series of `csv` files that I am using NumPy's `genfromtxt` function to turn into arrays.
They each have the following format:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC
  -2, 10,   10
  -1, 10,   10
   0, 10,   10
   1, 10,   10
   2, 10,   10
```

In the case of the above `csv`, using `genfromtxt(data.csv, delimeter=',', skip_header=1)` will generate an array with shape (5, 3). I can then iterate over each row, i.e.:

```
data_array = np.genfromtxt(data.csv, delimeter=',', skip_header=1)

for row in data_array:
    some_function(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

Where the function in the loop expects and requires three numbers.
This breaks down when the `csv` only contains one line of data, i.e.:

```
ColA, ColB, ColC,
   0,   -4,   10,
```

In this case, `for row in data_array` will be interpreted as looking at each number in the (1, 3)-shaped array individually, and so I cannot run the function on it. The data I have is a series of `csv` files and may or may not have more than one line of data. What is the proper way to handle this so that the `some_function(x, y, z)` can always be completed, regardless of the input array? I could do an `if`-statement to check if the array is 1D, but it seems like there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.reshape` with a wildcard (the `-1`) to force the data to be a 2d array:

```py
data_array = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=',', skip_header=1).reshape(-1,3)
```